# replace doublebackslash with single slash

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

How do I replace doublebackslash with single slash? couldnt find an example anywhere.
ie.

"c:\\this\\is\\a\\folder\\myfile.jpg" to "c:\this\is\a\folder\myfile.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`String.replace()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) function to do that:

```
var rx:RegExp = /\\\\/g;
var s:String = "c:\\\\folder\\\\folder\\\\folder\\\\file.ext";

trace ( s );
s = s.replace ( rx, "\\" );
trace ( s );
```

You need to escape the `\` character inside literal strings, that's why it's doubled in the code above.

Comment: Ive tried it before. tried again on your suggestion but doesnt work. any other way to do it? im sick of this. too complicated. also i need to replace all. maybe a regex solution?

Comment: @StephenNYC Sorry, I forgot that AS3 only performs a single replace unless the pattern is set to be global - the test string I used before only had a single `\\\` in it, so it worked. I edited my answer to correc this.

Comment: i feel im on a dead-end. my string doesnt have four backslash, only two backslash just like I specified in my question. it was taken from myfile.nativePath so I guess its a escaped single backslash. if apply the regex you provided, it doesnt have any effect and understandly it is because its already single backslash. But i need to build a string literal that only has one backslash as it need to be passed as parameter to command line executable _exactly_ like the one below. it doesnt accept forward slash so i have no choice.

Comment: actual text i need to generate: c:/windows/system32/rundll32.exe c:/windows/system32/shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo /pt "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\1368900308754.jpg" "Canon CP2000"

Comment: nevermind. i realized the values I see are from debugger only and If I use trace(), id see the actual value. my bad :P. thx for the help.

Comment: @StephenNYC You're welcome - I'm glad your problem is solved. :)